# Add custom block to layered navigation - best to Price

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, custom-block

Is anyone know how I can add custom block to price filter in layered navigation?

I curently moved my block with jQuery, but what if someone add more attributes? Maybe I could add class to price filter?

```
$('#narrow-by-list > div:nth-child(7)').append( $('#myBlock') );
```

Comment: do you want show `static block` ?

Comment: Yes, with my custom template, but not under layered navigation but inside.

Comment: could you add image where you want and How ?

Comment: In place when you have filter for price. There is no easy way and XML update there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set my price attribute to be last one and staid with my jQuery

```
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery'
        ],
        function(
            $
        ) {
            $('#narrow-by-list > div:last-child .filter-options-content').append( $('#myDiv') );


        }

    );

</script>
```

also can be done with if statement

```
if ($(".filter-current").is(':contains("Price")')) {
```